# JavaScript - Input value undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi
I'm new to web development and tring to understand some basics. To make it short, I have an input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="field" name="field" placeholder="Write something here...">
```

On separate file with JS extension I want to get the value from this `input`. I tried doing so in two ways, one in vanilla JS:

```
var value = document.getElementById('field').value;
```

This returns the correct value, and second with jQuery:

```
var value2 = $('#field').value;
```

And getting an 'undefined" from the second.

 Why is this so?

Comment: Do you have jquery in your file html file? 

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Lol, ofc I have it, and it's the first script loaded

Comment: jQuery 101, read documentation https://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,so you do this by using

```
var value = $("#field").val();
```

The reason the first approach works is because it returns the HTML element object and you assess its value property.(you can access any property of that element using `.` operator)

However using jquery returns **JQUERY object** and since it does not have a value property u can not access it. You need to use jqueries `val` function.

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you use the method val(). It would look like this :

```
var value2 = $('#field').val();
```

Comment: All right, this one works! But why just normal `.value` doesn't? Doesn't jQuery share the same methods than plane vanilla JS? That's something I'm trying to understand :D

Comment: It's because the $ selector will return an jquery object instead of a html element